# SQL Selecting between 3 tables- Cannot convert to int error

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

im having a issue with nested SQL code. Its fetching a INT variable based on a Nvarchar, i can't see why this would return a error so could use your help.

I have a table structure set out as follows-

- **SONGS_DB** *SONG_ID, SONG_NAME*
- **SONG_PLAYLIST** *SONG_PLAYLIST_ID, SONG_ID, PLAYLIST_ID*
- **Playlist** *PLAYLIST_ID, PLAYLIST_NAME*

Im trying to get all the songs from one playlist to show in a datagridviewer with the following code-

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\coolj\OneDrive\Documents\Loop\Loop\Songs_SQL.mdf;Integrated Security=True"}
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT SONG_ID, SONG_NAME FROM SONGS_DB WHERE SONG_ID IN (SELECT SONG_ID FROM SONG_PLAYLIST WHERE PLAYLIST_ID IN (SELECT PLAYLIST_ID FROM Playlist WHERE PLAYLIST_NAME = (@NAME)))", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)

    Dim Ada As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    Ada.Fill(Table)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
End Sub
```

However its returning the following error-

> 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Party Hits                    ' to data type int.'

Party hits is the name of the first playlist, im confused about this because i see no reason for party hits to be converted to a int. Any ideas?

Comment: try using selecteditem instead of selectedindex, you are comparing an int to text field in SQL

Comment: Please show how do you fill the ComboBox1 items collection. Do you use the DataSource or Items.Add ?

Comment: PLAYLIST_NAME appears to contain a "name" where as .SelectedIndex should be an int. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
```

returns the index of the current selected item in the combobox. And this is a number not the name of a playlist.

If you want to get the name of that playlist you could use

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

but the exact properies to use depends on how do you initialize the ComboBox content.
If you add a playlist one name at time you could use the method above, but if you fill the DataSource then you need to consider to extract the information from the object collection used to fill the datasource

For example, in case of filling the combo with a DataTable like in this code

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "....."}
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Playlist", con)
Dim Ada As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim Table As New DataTable()
Ada.Fill(Table)

' Here the collection of items is a collection of DataRowView
' and we tell the ComboBox what to display and what to use for the SelectedValue property
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "PLAYLIST_NAME"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "PlayList_ID"
ComboBox1.DataSource = Table
```

Then you could retrieve your Name with

```
Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
Dim name as String = drv("Name").ToString()
```

As a last advice I suggest you to change your query and use a more 'simple' and standard join statement

```
SELECT S.SONG_ID, S.SONG_NAME 
FROM SONGS_DB S 
   LEFT JOIN SONG_PLAYLIST SP ON S.SONG_ID = SP.SONG_ID
   LEFT JOIN Playlist P ON SP.PlayList_ID = p.PlayList_ID
WHERE p.PLAYLIST_NAME = @NAME",
```

Comment: Hi Steve thanks for the answer, ur top comment did resolve the error however the datagridviewer is still not populating. Thanks for the example but remember im looking to populate the grid with the song names and ids, not the playlists, which is in a seperate table

Comment: Well, you need to debug your code and check what values are in the variables. For example check what is the _Table.Rows.Count_ value after you have filled the table.

Comment: My second code snippet is an example on how to fill the ComboBox1, not the DataGridView, with the playlists' names without using a loop to insert the names one by one. It was there just to explain that different load methods require different extraction methods. If you insert the playlists names one by one then SelectedItem.ToString resolves the name